# Performance of changing css attributes via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, performance, search

I have a search function on a page that displays a couple of thousand entries.

it is a simple html searchbox:

```
    <form class="text-center" onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">
        <input id="coursesearchbox" autocomplete="off" type="search" oninput="filterCourses()">
    </form>
```

which is tied to a javascript function that hides all list items, and then shows all list items that match the search term in their data attribute. I'm also using a sleep function to only run the search when no new input is made for at least 250ms:

```
//filters courses in the course search tab
async function filterCourses() {
    if (coursesearchbox.value.length > 2) {
        hideAllCourses();
        var searchterm = coursesearchbox.value;
        await sleep(250);
        if (searchterm == coursesearchbox.value) {                
            var searchedCourses = document.querySelectorAll("[data-index*=" + searchterm + "]");
            for (var i = 0; i < searchedCourses.length; i++) {
                searchedCourses[i].style.display = "list-item";
            }
        }
    } else {
        showAllCourses();
    }
}

//hides all courses
function hideAllCourses() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sortableListItems.length; i++) {
        sortableListItems[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

//shows all courses
function showAllCourses() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sortableListItems.length; i++) {
        sortableListItems[i].style.display = "list-item";
    }
}
```

My problem is the performance of the script. What's funny for me, is that the slowest part is not actually searching for stuff, but deleting your search term, thus running showAllCourses(). Apparently the browser takes a long time switching back all the list items to display: list-item.

I tried using visibility: collapse instead of display:none, and that made it a lot faster, but unfortunately it does not work in Chrome.

Is there any other way I can speed this up? I think it might be slow because the browser re-renders the page everytime a list-item is switched back to display: list-item, so maybe if I could stop the page from re-rendering until the for-loop in showAllCourses() is done, that would help?